# How to determine if a string was compressed?

Tags: php, string, compression

How can I determine whether a string was compressed with [`gzcompress`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) (aparts from comparing sizes of string before/after calling [`gzuncompress`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php), or would that be the proper way of doing it) ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<sub>PRE: 
*I guess, if you send a **request**, you can immediately look into `$http_response_header` to see if the one of the items in the array is a variation of `Content-Encoding: gzip`. But this is not ideal!

there is a far better method.*


Here is **HOW TO...**


### Check if its GZIP. Like a BOSS!</sub>

> according to [GZIP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952#page-6):

#### The header of gzip content looks like this

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|ID1|ID2|CM |FLG|     MTIME     |XFL|OS | (more--&gt;)
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

the `ID1` and `ID2` **identify the content as GZIP**. And `CM` states that the **`ZLIB_ENCODING`** (the compression method) is `ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE` - which is customarily used by GZIP with all web-servers.

***oh!*** and they have fixed values:

- The value of **ID1** is **`"\x1f"`**
- The value of **ID2** is **`"\x8b"`**
- The value of **CM** is **`"\x08"`** *(or just 8...)*

### almost there:

`$is_gzip = 0 === mb_strpos($mystery_string , "\x1f" . "\x8b" . "\x08");`

### Working example

```
<?php
/** @link https://gist.github.com/eladkarako/d8f3addf4e3be92bae96#file-checking_gzip_like_a_boss-php */

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jerusalem");

while (ob_get_level() > 0) ob_end_flush();
mb_language("uni");
@mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');

header('Time-Zone: Asia/Jerusalem');
header('Charset: UTF-8');
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

function get($url, $cookie = '') {
  $html = @file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
      'method' => "GET",
      'header' => implode("\r\n", [''
        , 'Pragma: no-cache'
        , 'Cache-Control: no-cache'
        , 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2310.0 Safari/537.36'
        , 'DNT: 1'
        , 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8'
        , 'Accept: text/plain'
        , 'X-Forwarded-For: ' . implode(', ', array_unique(array_filter(array_map(function ($item) { return filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, $item, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); }, ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'REMOTE_ADDR', 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'SERVER_ADDR', 'REMOTE_ADDR']), function ($item) { return null !== $item; })))
        , 'Referer: http://eladkarako.com'
        , 'Connection: close'
        , 'Cookie: ' . $cookie
        , 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'
      ])
    ]]));

  $is_gzip = 0 === mb_strpos($html, "\x1f" . "\x8b" . "\x08", 0, "US-ASCII");

  return $is_gzip ? zlib_decode($html, ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE) : $html;
}

$html = get('http://www.pogdesign.co.uk/cat/');

echo $html;
```

#### What do we see here that is worth mentioning?

- start with initializing the PHP engine to use `UTF-8` (since we don't really know if the web-server **will** return a GZIP content.
- Providing the header `Accept-Encoding: gzip`, tells the web-sever, it **may** output a GZIP content.
- Discovering GZIP content (you should use the multi-byte functions with **ASCII encoding**).
- Finally returning the plain output, is easy using the `ZLIB` methods.

Comment: Works great for a [gzencode](http://php.net/gzencode)d string, but not for [gzcompress](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php)ed strings, which do not have the gzip-header, so I do:

`function isGzipped($in) {
        if (mb_strpos($in , "\x1f" . "\x8b" . "\x08")===0) {
                return true;
        } else if (@gzuncompress($in)!==false) {
                return true;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
}`

Comment: @futtta - nice addition, b.t.w. you should still keep `"US-ASCII"` (in `mb_strpos`)..

Answer (score 9):

A string and a compressed string are both simply sequences of bytes. You cannot really distinguish one sequence of bytes from another sequence of bytes. You *should know* whether a blob of bytes represents a compressed format or not from accompanying metadata.

If you really need to *guess* programmatically, you have several things you can try:

- Try to uncompress the string and see if the uncompress operation succeeds. If it fails, the bytes probably did not represent a compressed string.
- Try to check for obvious "weird" bytes like anything before `0x20`. Those bytes aren't typically used in regular text. There's no real guarantee that they occur in a compressed string though.
- Use [`mb_check_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_check_encoding) to see whether a string is valid in the encoding you suspect it to be in. If it isn't, it's probably compressed (or you checked for the wrong encoding). With the caveat that virtually any byte sequence is valid in virtually every single-byte encoding, so this'll only work for multi-byte encodings.

Comment: Sorry for being so clueless, but how can I perform the first bullet point? When I call `gzuncompress` on an uncompressed string it doesn't return me an error, just the same string.

Comment: Hmm, it returns `false` for me... `var_dump(gzuncompress('foobar'));`

Comment: Note that "\t" (tab), "\n" (newline), and "\r" (carriage return) are all likely to be in any string, and are all below 0x20.

Answer (score 2):

This work fine for me:

```
if (@gzuncompress($_xml)!==false) {
   // gzipped sring
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try `gzuncompress()` on the data as noted by @DiDiegodaFonseca. If it fails, it was not made by `gzcompress()`, or it was not faithfully transmitted.

If you really want to, you can check the first two bytes for a *zlib* header (not a gzip header, as incorrectly suggested in the accepted answer). `gzcompress()` produces a zlib stream, *not* a gzip stream. `gzencode()` is what produces a gzip stream. `gzdeflate()` produces a raw deflate stream.

[RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950) describes the zlib header. It is two bytes, where the two bytes taken as a big-endian 16-bit unsigned integer must be a multiple of 31. In addition to checking that, you can check that the low four bits of the first byte is 8 (1000), and that the high bit is zero.