# PHP file_get_contents() outputs Garbage HTML

Tags: php, encoding, file-get-contents

The webpage I am trying to access has `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag. I am using the following code to access the HTML.

```
$options = array(
'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header' => implode("\r\n", array(
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-type: text/html",
    "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    ))
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);

$webpage_html = file_get_contents($webpage_url, false, $context);
```

The HTML output for the **same webpage** comes out as garbage every now and then. It works flawlessly other times without any change in code. Here is a sample garbage output:

```
Xi�۸��_!�R2Y�PҬ�]��|��r썏�lM&S /�������5c'�]K@��h����d2������L�ǟ^�N���"��,(DsW�i�d��3�����53�I^�|��i�~�~�o�ʟ|
```

What can I do to make sure that I get the right HTML every time? Is there any problem with the encoding?

**Update**

The webpage opens successfully in the browser each time. I also copied the request headers from the browser but the problem persists. In case it helps, the website I am accessing is Amazon.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the webpage sends the html compressed? (Shouldn't file_get_contents decode that?)

Comment: Thanks @biziclop Can the webpage "randomly" send the HTML in compressed form?

Comment: There is no way to when I might get garbage characters and when I might get actual content.

Comment: @biziclop Can the compression part be verified using response headers?

Comment: Hi, I'm not an expert, just had this idea. If you save the garbage with .gz extension, does it decompress to something meaningful?

Comment: you could also try to use gzdecode on the string

Comment: @biziclop I will try it. :)

Comment: Thanks @BlackNetworkBit. Will `gzdecode` mess things up if the HTML is uncompressed?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding : "The server is overloaded and cannot afford the computational overhead induced by the compression requirement"

Comment: Noobie yes it can, you can check if the text is encoded with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975775/how-to-determine-if-a-string-was-compressed

Comment: You could try adding the `Accept-Encoding: identity` header too to the array to forbid any compression.

Comment: Thanks @biziclop. Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem. I still randomly get the garbage output.

Comment: BTW, what is the purpose of the `Content-type: text/html` in the *request*? Shouldn't that be only used at POST requests, where the content means the submitted form's content? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Comment: @biziclop When nothing worked I kept trying some other header values in the hope that they might resolve the error. :)

Comment: If you can find/make a concrete non-secret amazon link, you could share that too, so we could also play with it. :)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue consistently with Whooshkaa URLs, for example: https://player.whooshkaa.com/episode?id=330009